# KeyDown in jquery not updating when pressed

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the div to change the font size and update it on the screen. The following code works but there is a problem when you press a key you need to press another key to register the last key was pressed i dont know want that to happen. How would i make it update as soon as you press a key?

```
 $('#font_size_title').keydown(function() { 
 var font_size_title = $(this).val(); 
 $('#preview_title').css("font-size",font_size_title);
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead, like this:

```
$('#font_size_title').keyup(function() { 
  var font_size_title = $(this).val(); 
  $('#preview_title').css("font-size",font_size_title);
});
```

On [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) the value hasn't gotten the last letter yet, on [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) hoever, the value *has* been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try [using `.keyup()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

```
$('#font_size_title').keyup(function() { 
     // this.value is a little quicker than $(this).val()
   var font_size_title = this.value; 
   $('#preview_title').css("font-size",font_size_title);
});
```

This will register *after* the value has been entered. With `keydown` the input doesn't yet have the new value. That's why it takes another entry to get the last value.